# How do I perform a Latent Profile Analysis with both categorical and continuous variables in R?

Tags: r

I have 4 continuous variables (masculinity, femininity, partner's masculinity, partner's femininity) and 2 categorical variables (gender identity, partner's gender identity) and I'd like to perform an LPA. In my readings, it seems possible to use both categorical and continuous indicators for an LPA, but I haven't found a resource for actually doing it. I have attempted using the package tidyLPA but it doesn't allow me to specify which variables are categorical.

1. Am I correct to assume LPA can be used for both categorical and continuous indicators?
2. Is there a package in R that can handle this analysis?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. With regard to finding functions in R have you looked at the relevant task view which gives you a good overview of what is available: https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/.  For specific functions you could have a look at this post which still looks relevant: https://www.r-bloggers.com/finding-an-r-function/

Answer (score 0):

1. Am I correct to assume LPA can be used for both categorical and continuous indicators?

From the documentation of the package...

> Note that LPA works best with continuous variables (and, in some
>   cases, ordinal variables), but is not appropriate for dichotomous
>   (binary) variables.

Since categorical in this sense is much closer to binary than ordinal (unless you failed to mention that you meant ordinal not categorical) odds are strong it's inappropriate.

2. Is there a package in R that can handle this analysis?

See the comment from Peter above but it appears `tidyLPA` just wraps `mclust` and that `mclust` is capable of different models including categorical variables [see for example the](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mclust/vignettes/mclust.html) `EDDA` example.